# Random string split into characters

Tags: vba, random

I have a procedure, that generates a random string without any delimiter. I store return value of this as a string, but I would like to split this text into characters and after that examine each characters. I try to use above code to split string into characters, but it gives Type mismatch error.

```
Sub gen()
    Dim s As String
    s = textgen(4000, 5)
    Dim buff() As String
    ReDim buff(Len(s) - 1)

    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        buff(i - 1) = Mid$(s, i, 1)
    Next

    MsgBox (buff)  ' type mismatch
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string into array of characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195583/split-string-into-array-of-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `buff` is `string()` - an *array* of strings (VBA doesn't have a `Char` type).

`MsgBox` wants a `String` message, not an array of these; you'll have to `Join` the elements:

```
MsgBox Join(buff) 'no error
```