# VBA Breaking Up a Large String

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for advice on breaking up a very large string into many smaller strings.  As an example, I have a string of 5000 characters.  I have to split that string up into a sequential array of variables no larger than 450 characters.  Would the following be the most efficient way to do it?

```
Dim stringSection() as String

Private Sub extractSubStrings(giantString as String)

    Dim occurance as Integer

    occurance = 0
    For i = 1 to Len(giantString)
        If i Mod 450 = 1 Or i = Len(giantString) Then
            occurance = occurance + 1
            ReDim stringSection(occurance)
            stringSection = Mid(giantString, i-450, 450)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried Split?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195583/split-string-into-array-of-characters

Comment: Do you want the strings to be as balanced in length as possible?

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes, the strings cannot exceed 450 or it will cause errors downstream of this code.

Comment: @DanielGale I didn't know VBA had split, I'll take a look.

Comment: You are not trying to split on logical points with this code, does it matter?  you just want an array of strings 450 characters long?

Comment: @ScottCraner Sequential.  I want to chop it up, in order, 450 chars at a time.

Comment: If you can't make use of a delimiter, there are also several examples here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?501338-Split-string-at-length

Comment: @Jaberwocky - Why don't you use Mid() function? you can loop through the string until you reach the end if it

Comment: @aberforth did you look at the code?

Comment: @Jaberwocky - Yes I did... Did you check the below solutions? Both of them use `MID()` function so not sure what's your point here?

Comment: @aberforth My point is that I do use `Mid()` in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a VBA function that might help:

```
Function BreakUp(s As String, k As Long) As Variant
    'returns a 0-based variant array of strings of length <= k
    Dim i As Long, m As Long, n As Long
    Dim chunks As Variant
    n = Len(s)
    m = Int(n / k)
    If n - k * m > 0 Then 'leftover chunk at end
        ReDim chunks(0 To m)
    Else
        ReDim chunks(0 To m - 1)
    End If
    For i = 0 To UBound(chunks)
        chunks(i) = Mid(s, 1 + k * i, k)
    Next i
    BreakUp = chunks
End Function
```

After you grab the array then you can iterate over it, although if *all* you want to do is iterate over it then the above function has no real benefit over simply using `Mid` in a loop in the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that keeps things simple, utilising `Split` based on a forced delimiter. Change the delimiter to something suitable if your string can contain a `/`

```
Function cut_into_pieces(txt As String, piece_length As Long) As Variant
    Dim x As Long, delim As String
    delim = "/"
    pieces = ""
    For x = 0 To Int(Len(txt) / piece_length)
        this_piece = Mid(txt, 1 + (x * piece_length), piece_length)
        If this_piece <> "" Then cut_into_pieces = cut_into_pieces & this_piece & delim
    Next
    cut_into_pieces = Split(Left(cut_into_pieces, Len(cut_into_pieces) - 1), delim)
End Function
```

You would call this with `arr = cut_into_pieces(giantString, 450)`

Answer (score 0):

ReDim use a lot of memory and it's enever a good practice to use them in Loops where you will need to ReDim a big ampunt of times. Have you used Collection and Do Until Loops? Why don't you try this?

```
Private Sub extractSubStrings(ByVal giantString As String)

    Dim colOfSmallStrings As Collection

    Set colOfSmallStrings = New Collection

    Do
        colOfSmallStrings.Add Left$(giantString, 450)
        giantString = Mid$(giantString, 451, Len(giantString))

    Loop Until Len(giantString) < 450

    ' Add final piece of string
    colOfSmallStrings.Add Left(giantString, 450)
End Sub
```