# Cant fill array with characters in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Someone knows what should i do?
it says expected array

```
dim szamok As String
szamok = Range("f2")
Dim hossz As Integer

ReDim karakterek(1 To Len(szamok)) As Characters

For i = 1 To Len(szamok)
karakterek(i) = szamok(i)
Next i
```

Comment: (1) You don't `Redim` if you haven't dimmed in the first place; (2) I think your declaration should be of type `String` rather than `Characters` if it contains text.

Comment: I have a int "f2". those are 0 and 1 numbers. i want to make them into a character based array. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Also `szamok(i)` is wrong as `szamok` is a string not an array. So if F2 contains "Fred" do you want an array of 4 elements, "F", "R","E" and "D"?

Comment: Yes. i Redimed the karakterek array because it doesnt let me dim because of 1 to Len(szamok)

Comment: So F2 contains a series of 0s and 1s? Could you attach a screenshot? When you initially dim it you don't declare dimensions, just use `Dim karakterek() As String`.

Comment: `szamok` is not an array, it is a string. To get each character from it, use: `= mid(szamok, i, 1)` intead of `szamok(i)`

Comment: How can i attach a screenshot?

Comment: You can upload your image to imgur.com and post a link to it. Someone with enough repuation will be able to embed it for you

Comment: @SJR, you don't need to use Dim if you ReDim before use. You just can't use Preserve.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13196878/78522

Comment: @user10735198 - I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you need:

```
Dim szamok As String
Dim hossz As Long
Dim karakterek As Variant

szamok = Range("F2").Value

ReDim karakterek(1 To Len(szamok))

For i = 1 To Len(szamok)
    karakterek(i) = Mid(szamok, i, 1)
Next i
```

Changes to original code:

1. `Dim karakterek` as `Variant` before `Redim`
2. Get characters from `szamok` using `Mid`

Comment: Thank you very much. Im working on a project where i convert binary to decimal but i cant deal with the fracture binaries so i decided to deal first with the integer and then calculate the fracture part here is my code yet

Answer (score 0):

As [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13196878/78522), you can simply use

```
Dim bytes() as Byte
bytes = StrConv("Xmas", vbFromUnicode)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have any tip how to convert a fracture binary to a decimal?