# Is there a faster way to replace accented characters?

Tags: excel, vba, diacritics

I have this code that replaces all accented characters except in row 6. However, this macro takes a long time because it goes through every cell/letter, is there any way to make this any faster by making it ignore cells that don't have any accents in them?

```
Const sFm As String = "ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ"
Const sTo As String = "SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyy"

Dim i As Long, employeews As Worksheet
Dim rowsix() As Variant

Set employeews = DestWb.Sheets(1)

'Don't replace row 6
rowsix = employeews.Rows(6).Value


For i = 1 To Len(sFm)
    employeews.Cells.Replace Mid(sFm, i, 1), Mid(sTo, i, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True
Next i

employeews.Rows(6).Value = rowsix
```

Comment: I would think to choose a range I want to replace values within, then loop through the special characters to replace, as a whole, within the range.  The only real caveat to remember is that this WILL affect formulas.  `For i = lbound(arr) to ubound(arr) // ws.range("a1:z5".replace(accentArr(i),noAccentArr(i))`

Answer (score 2):

Putting comment as an answer so the code is more readable:

---

I would think to choose a range I want to replace values within, then loop through the special characters to replace, as a whole, within the range. The only real caveat to remember is that this **will** affect formulas.

```
dim accentArr as variant, noAccentArr as variant
'accent and noaccent need to have same upper bound for this approach!
accentArr = Array("Š","Ž","š") 'quick mockup
noAccentArr = Array("S","Z","s") 
dim i as long
For i = lbound(accentArr) to ubound(accentArr)
    ws.range("a1:z5").replace(accentArr(i),noAccentArr(i))
Next i
```

Rather than going character by character in the cell, you at least do a mass replace for specific characters... this also allows your `Range()` to start at row 7, as to not include row 6.

---

Postscript, see: [Split string into array of characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195583/split-string-into-array-of-characters) if you want to utilize the existing string without having to manually split out the string of characters into an array.

Comment: Hint to syntyax: Think there's no valid global range replacement via `ws.range("a1:z5").replace(accentArr(i),noAccentArr(i))` and standing alone without assigning back to range or datafield :-)

Comment: [MS Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function
): `Replace(expression, find, replace, [ start, [ count, [ compare ]]])`

Answer (score 1):

In line with what everyone else is saying, and not really knowing what you are considering as bad performance, you could try someting like so.  It uses a `dictionary` which is populated with your from and to strings, split into characters and their replacements where the from is the `key` and the to is the `item`  The `keys()` and `items()` of the dictionary are array's so using them rather than slicing the string each time and the dictionary will be available again.

```
Private d As Scripting.Dictionary

Const sFrom As String = "ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ"
Const sTo As String = "SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyy"

Sub PopulateReplacements()

Dim s As String
Dim l As Long

Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary

For l = 1 To Len(sFrom)
    If Not d.Exists(Mid(sFrom, l, 1)) Then _
                d.Add Mid(sFrom, l, 1), Mid(sTo, l, 1)
Next l

End Sub

Sub TestReplacing()

Dim s As String
Dim l As Long

s = "ÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔ"
s = "_Ÿ_À_Á_Â_Ã_Ä_Å_Ç_È_É_Ê_Ë_Ì_Í_Î_Ï_Ð_Ñ_"
s = sFrom

If d Is Nothing Then
    PopulateReplacements
End If

For l = 0 To UBound(d.Keys())
    s = Replace(s, d.Keys()(l), d.Items()(l))
Next l

Debug.Print s

End Sub
```