# VBA, How to pass in a string argument, convert to single character array and resize according to non-numerical values?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string, split

Ok,

To all those who may come across this question, this is a problem I have been banging my head against for the past two weeks and have made little or no progress, so any help would be extremely welcome.

Here's the set up; then I will follow with an excerpt of the code I have written:

I am writing a function to get a very *specific* formula for each file name in a given folder. This naturally requires me to write a program which can take string arguments (in this case, excel file names) from a very broad domain of possibilities and yield a very specific output based on some key -and highly unique- parameters. Hence, my function is bijective and the set of arguments and set of products are massive; therefore, I am in the process of writing a sub-process for this function which partitions the string argument, by character, into a corresponding array, remove all the unnecessary characters, concatenate the remaining characters into the output string, and then go through a series of checks to enforce whatever name-formula the file requires. For now, I am just focused on splitting the string into an array, removing all non-numeric characters and combining the remaining characters back into a single string.

Naturally, I have tried the split function, but to my knowledge VBA doesn't support the splitting of a string into single characters. So I have written the following code, which, admittedly, is a bit inelegant, but I think in principle must work. -It does not. Would someone kindly tell me why it doesn't, and make a recommendation for altering it.

```
Dim arr() As Variant
        For i = Len(strArg) To i = 1
            If IsNumeric(Mid$(strArg, i, 1)) = True Then
            arr(i - 1) = Mid$(strArg, i, 1)
            Else: arr(i - 1) = ""
            End If
        Next
    newStr = Join(arr())
```

arr() always returns empty, so newStr is always "". Yet there are always numeric values in each string argument. -I can't imagine why I am getting this result. If I use ReDim arr(Len(strArg)), I get Len(strArg) number of " " back....

Thanks in advance to whomever may provide help.

Comment: While I'm not convinced an array is necessary interim point merely to perform replaces or removal of characters, you can check out this [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13195712/2221001) for converting a string into an array of its characters.

Comment: You need to size `arr` appropriately and your loop is wrong: `For i = Len(strArg) To 1 step -1`

Comment: You could also assign the string to a byte array directly and process that.

Comment: Why not `If IsNumeric(Mid$(strArg, i, 1)) Then nStr = nStr & Mid$(strArg, i, 1)` (and going from 1 to Len(strArg) ofc) instead of using an array for it?

Comment: Thank you both to Rory and Notus Panda, you have solved the issue for me. I am exceedingly grateful.

Comment: Posted an alternative using `FilterXML` as well as a function to atomize a string into a single character array based upon @JNevill 's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you need to split it into an array for this.  Your description says you only want to have numeric characters returned in a new string variable.  A function like this should work for you:

```
Function GetNumbers(ByVal arg_sText As String) As String
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sChar As String
    Dim sNumbers As String
    
    For i = 1 To Len(arg_sText)
        sChar = Mid(arg_sText, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(sChar) Then sNumbers = sNumbers & sChar
    Next i
    
    GetNumbers = sNumbers
    
End Function
```

Then just call it in your code like this:

```
newStr = GetNumbers(strArg)  'Example: "ab1c2d" = "12"
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively use a Regular Expression

```vb
Function NumOnly(s As String) As String
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "[^0-9]+"
         NumOnly = .Replace(s, "")
    End With  
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

As a further approach to the existing solutions, I'd like to demonstrate how to use the ►[`FilterXML()` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filterxml-function-4df72efc-11ec-4951-86f5-c1374812f5b7) and to check valid results.

The proposed function `NumsOnly()` consists only of three steps:

- a) execute an XPath search upon xml content which has been created by `getXML()`
- b) check valid results via procedure `check`
- c) return the function result as new formed string

Coming close to the requirements in OP this includes also a way to
convert a string to a single character array (c.f. @JNevill 's comment to OP) and
to build a well-formed xml string as base for `Filter.XML` (see function `getXML()`) .

**Main function `NumsOnly()`**

```
Function NumsOnly(ByVal s As String) As String
'Purp: recognizes only numeric values in comparisons
'Note: no findings and single digit results are handled by proc check
    Const xpath As String = "//*[.>0]"  ' get only digits out of atomized characters
'a) execute XPath search upon xml content
    Dim x: x = Application.FilterXML(getXML(s), xpath)
'b) check valid results
    check x
'c) return only-nums string as function result
    NumsOnly = x
End Function
```

**Helper function `getXML()`**

*Extended udf based on [Split string into array of characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13195712/2221001)*

```
Function getXML(ByVal s As String)
'Purp: return well-formed xml content string as base for FilterXML function
'1) atomize string elements into array
    Dim buff() As String: buff = Split(StrConv(s, vbUnicode), Chr$(0))
    ReDim Preserve buff(UBound(buff) - 1)
'2) return valid xml content string
    getXML = "<ch><c>" & Join(buff, "</c><c>") & "</c></ch>"
End Function
```

**Procedure `check`**

*As FilterXML returns findings of more than one element as a 2-dim array,
non-findings as `Error 2015` and a single element as stand-alone value, it is necessary to distinguish between the returned var types:*

```
Sub check(ByRef x, Optional ErrorResult As String = "")
'Purp: provide for correct xml result by checking var types
    Select Case VarType(x)
        Case vbError        ' non-findings (Error 2015)
            x = ErrorResult
        Case Is >= vbArray  ' 2-dim results (if more than 1 element)
            x = Join(Application.Transpose(x), vbNullString)
        'Case Else          ' single element (here: digit, i.e. Double)
    End Select
End Sub
```